# Создал глобальный двухмерный массив, его не видно через System.out.println();

Tags: java, массивы

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

/**
 * Created by illyaosiyuk on 25.03.17.
 */
public class Reader {



    public static int grows;
    public static int gcolumns;

    public static double[][] arr = new double[grows][gcolumns];
    public static String[] obj = new String[grows];


    public static void line(String path) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))){


            String line;
            int count = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                count++;
            }
            grows = count;

            int rows = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){

                String[] a = line.split(",");
                gcolumns = a.length;

                for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
                    if(i != a.length - 1){
                        arr[rows][i] = Double.parseDouble(a[i]);
                    }else {
                        obj[i] = a[i];
                    }
                }
                rows++;
            }
            make_Object();

        }
    }

    public static void make_Object(){
        for(int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
            Object object = new Object(arr[i],obj[i]);
        }

    }


}
```

Исключение

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: Можете объяснить яснее, что у вас не получается?

Comment: Мне нужно написать ИИ, который будет считывать с файла числа типа  double и последней колонкой будет имя обьекта.
Я считываю это в два разных массива а потом пытаюсь проверить зашло оно или нет через sout, но мне выдает ошибку

Comment: @illyaosik какая ошибка? Добавьте [mcve]

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Reader.make_Object(Reader.java:51)
 at Reader.line(Reader.java:45)
 at Main.main(Main.java:9)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 0):

Тут массивы не инициализируются(нет строк `new double[size1][size2]` и `new String[size3]` для массивов arr и obj соответственно). Вероятно в этом и проблема: массивы не созданы, а вы пытаетесь получить к ним доступ

Comment: Переписал, но все равно нет ничего

Comment: @illyaosik ну конечно, grows и gcolumns чему равны? они будут проинициализированы нулем, соответственно и создается массив нулевой длины, вы опять используете то, что еще не создали. Сделайте хотя бы `public static int grows = 10;` и `public static int gcolumns = 10;`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int grows;
public static int gcolumns;

public static double[][] arr = new double[grows][gcolumns];
public static String[] obj = new String[grows];
```

Ну вот вы создали два массива размеростью 0 на 0. т.к. переменные явно не инициализированы. 
А затем читаете в цикле из файла их значения и пытаетесь работать с массивом. Может сначала считаете размеры, потом проинициализируете, а только затем будете с ним работать?
И вообще - глобальные массивы это адский муветон. Это вам не бейсик.